# How to resolve this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel"

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Am getting the selected values from the drop down and adding into the jlist. But am getting this error for my fields only (datepicker field and another combo box field). I initialized and used default list model. Everytime am clearing my list before adding. But when i selected a value in my combo box it shows error as

```
4 Mar, 2014 7:39:23 AM adminscreen.taskallocationscreennew t_dateActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
    at adminscreen.taskallocationscreennew.t_dateActionPerformed(taskallocationscreennew.java:820)
    at adminscreen.taskallocationscreennew.access$600(taskallocationscreennew.java:50)
    at adminscreen.taskallocationscreennew$7.actionPerformed(taskallocationscreennew.java:579)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.fireActionPerformed(JXDatePicker.java:876)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker.commitEdit(JXDatePicker.java:706)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI.commit(BasicDatePickerUI.java:901)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.monthViewActionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1374)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.actionPerformed(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1349)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.fireActionPerformed(JXMonthView.java:1797)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.commitSelection(JXMonthView.java:1695)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicMonthViewUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMonthViewUI.java:2075)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Below is my code:

```
   private void d_pagetypeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)          {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   System.out.println("d_pagetype"+d_pagetype.getSelectedItem());

   try {

            if(l_storieslist.getModel() != null)
            {
        ((DefaultListModel) l_storieslist.getModel()).clear();
        listf(directoryName);
            }

            else
            {
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(taskallocationscreennew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    l_storieslist.setModel(fileNameList);
    l_storieslist.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

}
```

Comment: yes am using this in all my combo boxes...i have four combo boxes

Comment: comments seem to have been wiped, but are you calling l_storieslist.setModel(x) anywhere, and are you sure that x is a DefaultListModel?

Comment: Can I just point out that the method listed in the stack trace (`t_dateActionPerformed`) is not the same as the example code (`d_pagetypeActionPerformed`)

Comment: am clearing list values and then only am adding the list model into jlist

Comment: Why don't you add a `System.out.println( l_storiesList.getModel().getClass()` debug statement to your code. Then you will have the answer. We can't help without you posting a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It's pretty clear what the model class is - it's javax.swing.JList$3 as the stack trace shows, which is this: http://puu.sh/7iczr.png. Aka, the default model class when you construct a new JList. He's missing a setModel call to a DefaultListModel somewhere, or it's not happening when he thinks it is.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
l_storieslist.setModel(fileNameList);
```

fileNameList is instance of JList, it should be instance of DefaultListModel.

Probably you don't need to set the model again. Instead do the operation on the existing model. You can get the reference to the existing model like you did in your code

```
ListModel model = l_storieslist.getModel();
```

and perform operations of adding/removing whatever list items you want.

Answer (score 0):

The model should be set at List initialization (spotted [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27401815/javax-swing-JList-3-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-swing-DefaultListModel.html))

> by default, it uses an innerclass impl for model, you need to set DefaultListModel explicitly while constructing the list!